Can I cite and reference a book in a research or graduate work if I don't know its license?
Is it strictly legal to cite or reference to books found on the internet in my graduate work or research or not? I don't know their license, but heard about fair use rule or law in the US. The thing I want to do is to cite and reference to some sentences describing some concepts. The 3 books were published in the US/UK in 1939, 1978 and 1986.

Have you looked for more information on fair use via Google or another search engine?

@user176372 These explanations are too long and obscure to me, I might miss some important details, English is not my native language. The question is basically: is citing legal in research? Does it depend on how I got the book? I found it on one of the internet e-book libraries but not sure if its license makes it available to cite or reference in my case. I also started to doubt if the e-book library is legal in the US, but for some reason it exists and hasn't been blocked for years.

Copyright law is about the right to copy content.  It places no limits on your ability to talk about copyrighted works, such as by citing or discussing them.  You are free to do so.  The license or copyright status of the work is irrelevant.
Even short quotes of the verbatim text of a source are usually protected under fair use or fair dealing laws.
If you are citing a book which you copied or downloaded illegally, you may be at risk of legal consequences for the act of copying or downloading it, but not for the act of citing it.
If unsure, consult your university librarians.  They are experts in this area and a large part of their job is sharing their knowledge with students.
